# get already sorted column names in ext js grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm using below code in order to get the already sorted column names from grid by using ext js even My grid(myGrid) is working correctly

```
function onClick(){
     var grid = myGrid.getStore().sortInfo.field;
     alert("grid")
}
```

I'm getting error "object is null or not an object"

please help

Comment: "myGrid" does not define in this function. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: myGrid has already been defined in my program and the same is being displayed in screen. I need to get the names of shorted columns (ASC\DESC) in grid only.

Comment: myGrid has already been defined in in my program and same is displaying correctly on the screen.

I need help for getting the names for already sorted columns(ASC or DESC) from above myGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sort the store with sencha store function.

Sencha api: [sort store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort)

```
//sort by a single field
myStore.sort('myField', 'DESC');

//sorting by multiple fields
myStore.sort([{
    property : 'age',
    direction: 'ASC'
}, {
    property : 'name',
    direction: 'DESC'
}]);

// Sort the store using the existing sorter set.
myStore.sort();
```

In your case:

```
myGrid.getStore().sort('myField', 'DESC');
```

Comment: I don't feel that the answer is useful. I too want the solution for retrieving the current sort fields.

Comment: It's useful solution for @green viper, maybe you need sort functionality on proxy ajax request (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax) or other solution. Create a new thread to expose it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what the author meant:

```
myGrid.getStore().sorters.keys
```

It return an array with dataIndexes of sorted columns.

If you need more detailed info then:

```
myGrid.getStore().sorters.items
```

Is the way to go. It gives you an array of objects like this:

    `{
        direction: "ASC",
        property: "yourDataIndex",
        root: "data"
    }`